# Authentication homepage won't show

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a simple form of authentication but when I load it into my browser using `localhost:8000` it won't load the homepage? . First I created a database (auth) after that I written the `php artisan make:auth` in my cmd then I created my tables `php artisan migrate`. When I try to load my `localhost:8000` it only shows me the Laravel 5 but it won't show the authentication homepage. Any help? By the way I'm using Laravel 5.2

**route.php**

```
<?php
   Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
   });

   Route::auth();

   Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
?>
```

**HomeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}
}
```

I follow some steps on the Internet how to create a authentication homepage. So this is my desire output below.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `artisan make:auth` will generate authentication views and routes, but they won't show on the home page. Check `routes.php` and your `HomeController`.

Comment: @TheFallen please see my updated post.

Comment: @Francisunoxx Please use `Route::auth();` in the **'web'** middleware and then go to localhost:8000/login

Answer (score 0):

`Route::auth();` registers the following routes:

```
    // Authentication Routes...
    get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
    get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
    post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
```

You should be able to access them without a problem.

Comment: You don't have to put them, `Route::auth();` already puts them for you. Do you get some error?

Comment: I tried your code but still doesn't work. No I didn't get any error.

Comment: Can you explain what do you do and what do you get in a result?